# Building an object-oriented DBAL class that implements lazy-loaded connections

Tags: php, database, oop

I'm trying to make my application as OOP oriented as possible, and I'm wondering of a secure and clean way to implement my database. Essentially what I have is a Database type with several methods such as connect(), add(), update(), remove(), to manipulate the database. Is there a good way to implement this automatically whenever I need to connect to a database in another class? Or if there is a good book that deals with creating this type of design. Sorry if this is unclear.

Comment: You can just use the [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) object.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest for you to borrow few concepts from MVC. In this case the ideas about Model layer. A properly written Model layer is made up from two main types of instances:

- domain objects: responsible for all the domain business logic (read more [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_object))
- data access objects: which handle all the storage. Usually implemented as DataMappers.

The idea is that *Domain Objects* are completely unaware that there is any kind of storage. An they do not care. The business logic for making an invoice does not change if information comes from SQL database, remote REST API or screenshot of a MSWord document.

On the other hand, *Data Access Objects* have no indication of how business logic works. The just receive an object, and either fetch data into it , or stores data from it to some persistent medium. If you want to lean more about DataMappers, then you should [read here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) or [watch this](https://vimeo.com/21173483) presentation (slides [here](http://www.slideshare.net/BachkoutouToutou/confoo-2011-advanced-oo-patterns)).

Now about lazy connections. This is how i would implement it :

```
// somewhere in bootstrap.php

/* --snip-- */
$connection = function(){ 
    $instance = new PDO( .... );
    $instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $instance;
};

$mapperFactory = new MapperFactory( $connection );
/* --snip-- */
```

And the implementation of that MapperFactory would look like:

```
// different file where the class is defined
class MapperFactory
{
    protected $connection_provider = null;
    protected $connection = null;

    public function __construct( $connection_provider )
    {
        $this->connection_provider = $connection_provider;
    }

    public function build( $classNname )
    {
        $instance = new $className;
        if ( $instance instanceof  SqlDataMapper )
        {
            if ( !$this->connection )
            {
                $this->establishConnection(); 
            }
            $instance->setConnection( $this->connection );
        }

        return $instance;
    }

    protected function establishConnection()
    {
        $this->connection = call_user_func( $this->connection_provider );
    }
}
```

All you need, it to pass around this `$mapperFactory` from the *bootstrap* to the classes which will user it.

If you are serious about learning OO approach to solving problem, then this would be the mandatory list of reading materials (the code examples will be in Java, but the ideas are what's important here):

- [Inheritance, Polymorphism, & Testing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc)
- [Global State and Singletons](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI)
- [Don't Look For Things!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0)

Answer (score 0):

Well the esiest way would just be to use PDO or Mysqli wrapped in some kind of DB manager that can read information from configuration that you set up at boostrapping. Then you would either make this class a singleton or use some kind of automated dependency injection to make sure you can get at it from every in your model and controller layers (assuming mvc/hmvc).

Ill go with a singleton since its pretty brief example to demonstrate:

```
class DatabaseManager
{
   protected $_connections = array();

   protected static $_configPath = 'config';

   protected static $_configFile = 'databases.json'

   protected static $_instance;

   protected $_defaultConnection;


   protected __construct()
   {
      $this->_loadConfig();
   }

   protected loadConfig()
   {
      if(!($file = realpath(self::$_configPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . self::$_configFile)) {
          throw new Exception('Configuration file does not exist.');
      }

      if(!($config = file_get_contents($file)) {
         throw new Exception('Could not read configuration.');
      }

      if(!($configData = json_decode($config, true)) {
         throw new Exception('Could not parse JSON.');
      }

      $this->_connections = $configData;
   }

   public static function setConfigDir($path)
   {
       self::$_configDir = $path;
   }

   public static function setConfigFile($filename) {
      self::$_configFile = $filename;
   }

   public static function getInstance() {
      if(!self::$_instance) {
         self::$_instance = new self();
      }

      return self::$_instance;
   }

   public static function getConnection($key = null) {
       $instance = self::getInstance();
       $key = null === $key ? $instance->_defaultConnection : $key;

       if(!$instance->_connections[$key] instanceof PDO) {
          if(is_array($instance->_connections[$key]) {
             $instance->_connections[$key] = new PDO($instance->_connections[$key]['dsn'], $instance->_connections[$key]['username'], $instance->_connections[$key]['password']);

          } else {
             throw new Exception ("Invalid connection \"$key\"");
          }
       }

       return $instance->_connections[$key];       
   }
}
```

Now youll probably want to validate the configuration file (make sure it contains at least one connection, and make sure each connection definition has a dsn, username and password). And you would probably want better error hadling, but that being said usage of this would be like:

In you bootstrap:

```
DatabaseManager::setConfigPath('/path/to/config');
DatabaseManager::setConfigFile('databases.json');
```

Then pretty much anywhere in your app:

```
// get a connection - they are lazy loaded - YAY!
$pdoObject = DatabaseManager::getInstance()->getConnection('my_connection_name');

// use PDO as normal
$stmt = $pdoObject->prepare('SELECT * from test');
$stmt->execute();
// do stuff with statement and returned results
```

Now with all that said if you want more than a manager to PDO i would recommend [Doctrine2 DBAL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal.html) or if you want/need a full ORM [Doctrine2 ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html)

Comment: +1 to this. I have my db manager set up in a similar fasion. Using a singleton/factory pattern for each connection.

Comment: it might be just my private bias, but i would describe most of it as "class oriented" not "object oriented" code.

Answer (score -1):

Or even better, use PHP ActiveRecord:

[ActiveRecord Site](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/)

An object-relational mapping pattern.